# Laplace Transform IVP, trouble getting inverse transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am given the IVP $y^{(4)}-4y'''+6y''-4y'+y=0,\ y(0)=0,\ y'(0)=1,\ y''(0)=0,\ y'''(0)=1.$
I have taken the Laplace transform of all the terms, and have ended up with 
$$F(s)=\frac{(s-2)^2}{(s-1)^4}+\frac{3}{(s-1)^4}.$$ Do I have to use partial fractions to decompose these further, or is there a simpler way to simplify these expressions?

Comment: Yes, you can do the partial fraction expansion as $$-\dfrac{2}{(s-1)^3}+\dfrac{4}{(s-1)^4}+\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2}$$ This should be much easier to work with. Having said that, are you sure this is the correct Laplace Transform?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the post, the $1$ should be a $y$. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: That is now correct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

$$
 \frac{2{{t}^{3}}\,{{ {}e}^{t}}}{3}-{{t}^{2}}\,{{ {}e}^{t}}+t\,{{ {}e}^{t}} 
$$
you can use any computer algebra system.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write $F(s)$ as the derivative or integral of some other function $G(s)$ then you can use #30 or #31 from: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Otherwise you need to use partial fraction decomposition.